# Distributing 7 red balls and 2 blue balls into 3 containers such that in each container, there are 3 balls and at least 2 of them are red balls.

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to distribute 7 distinguishable red balls and 2 distinguishable blue balls into 3 indistinguishable containers such that in each container, there are 3 balls and at least 2 of them are red balls?

---

I got $\dfrac{\binom{7}{2}\cdot\binom{5}{2}\cdot\binom{3}{2}\cdot 3\cdot 2}{3!}=630$, because there are $\binom{7}{2}\cdot\binom{5}{2}\cdot\binom{3}{2}$ to distribute 6 red balls so each container has 2 balls. Next, there are $3$ containers for the last 7 ball and 2 ways to distribute the 2 blue balls. Lastly, divide by $3!$ because the containers are indistinguishable. However, this is the wrong answer. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my solution?

Thanks!

Comment: When you start distributing 6 red balls ( can be a,b,c,d,e,f,  or a,b,c,d,e,g or ... ) and then distribute the last red ball ( can be a or b or c ...) you have a lot of situations that you count twice or even more.  You can check what happens when you don't have the constraint '<at least 2 red balls in each container>', the number that you obtain is 336, less than 630 !

Comment: For a corrected solution, I would recommend noticing that "at least 2 red balls per container" will imply here because of the way the numbers work out that exactly one of the containers will have exactly three red balls, and the other two containers will each have two red balls.  Pick what three red balls go together in $\binom{7}{3}$ ways.  Then, among the remaining red balls, one of them is "smallest" (*according to whatever order you choose to apply*).  Pick what other red ball and what blue ball go with it in $3\cdot 2$ ways.  This gives a final answer of $\binom{7}{3}\cdot 3\cdot 2=210$

Comment: When we start with combinatorics, it is useful to check if all results are consistent. Total is $336$. We have 2 ways to put 7 red balls in 3 containers, it can be 3+2+2 or 3+3+1 ; the balanced one (3+2+2) is a little more frequent that the unbalanced one (3+3+1) ; $210$ for the balanced one, hence $126$ for the unbalanced one, it seems consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way they can be distributed to meet the conditions is:

$red\,:\;3-2-2$
$blue:\;0-1-1$

We need to compute separately for each color and multiply

thus $\Large\left(\frac{7!}{3!2!2!}\cdot\frac{1}{2!}\right) \times \left(\frac{2!}{0!1!1!}\cdot\frac{1!}{2!}\right)=210$

*Explanation*

Had they been distinct boxes, the number would have been

$\Large\left(\frac{7!}{3!2!2!}\cdot\frac{3!}{2!}\right) \times \left(\frac{2!}{0!1!1!}\cdot\frac{3!}{2!}\right)$

but as they are identical, we have replaced the numerators of the second term for each color by $1$

---

**An obsevation**

I find that some answers/answers in comments have been obtained with very little computation, which is all to the good, but I am a fan of the multinomial coefficient, and that is because the process is so mechanical that it can be done even in half-sleep.

- For putting **distinct** balls into **distinct** boxes, you just need to multiply two multinomial coefficients for $[Lay\;down\;pattern]\times[Permute\; pattern]$

eg if you roll a die $8$ times, and get a pattern $1-2-0-3-1-1$, the answer is

$\dbinom{8}{1,2,0,3,1,1}\dbinom{6}{3,1,1,1}$

Better simplified and understood as **permutations** (where $0!,1!$ etc can be conveniently removed), so

$\dfrac{8!}{2!3!}\times\dfrac{6!}{3!}$

And the **only** change required for **distinct** balls to **identical** boxes is to change the numerator of the second term to $1$, thus $\dfrac{8!}{2!3!}\times\dfrac{1}{3!}$

Answer (score 3):

**For another view point :**

As @trueblueanil said , the only possible distribution can be done when one boxes has $3$ red balls and the other two take $2$ red balls. The blue balls will go directly to complement them to $3$ balls

To make our calculation easier , think that the boxes are distinct in the beginning.

**Step 1-)** Determine which box will have $3$ red balls by $C(3,1)$.

**Step 2-)** Distribute red balls to $3$  distinct boxes such that one box has three ball , the others have two balls by $C(7,3)\times C(4,2) \times C(2,2)$

**Step 3-)** Distribute $2$ blue balls to those boxes which have $2$ red balls such that each box will take $1$ blue balls ,so we can do it by $C(2,1) \times C(1,1)$.

Now we found the number of distributing $7$ distinct red balls and $2$ distinct blue balls to $3$ distinct boxes such that one box has $3$ red balls and the other two boxes have $2$ red balls and $1$ blue ball. It is equal to $$C(3,1)\times C(7,3)\times C(4,2) \times C(2,2) \times C(2,1) \times C(1,1)=1260$$

However, we know that those three boxes were identical , so divide the result by $3!$ to convert distinct boxes into identical.

$$\frac{C(3,1)\times C(7,3)\times C(4,2) \times C(2,2) \times C(2,1) \times C(1,1)}{3!}=210$$

Comment: I have taken note of your nice explanation of first solving for distinct boxes and dividing by $k!$ for identical boxes where $k$ is the number of boxes. Only, I am a fan of the multinomial doemula, it saves my poor brain from thinking ! (+1)

Comment: @trueblueanil wow , it is good to hear nice comments from you my friend , but i am disagree with the statement of " saves my poor brain from thinking" ,because i learnt many many things from your brillant mind , and takes many notes to my combinatorics notes from your answer and comments :) You may not aware but you are one of the my best teachers in M.S.E..

Comment: Thanks, but you are being too kind. I, too, inspired by you, have started dabbling in generating functions and Smirnov words. Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

You want to count partitions in three sets of the set $\{r_1,\ldots ,r_7,b_1,b_2\}$ (there $r_k$ represents red balls, and $b_k$ blue balls) such that every set in the partition had exactly three balls and the blue balls cannot be together in one of the sets.

Note that these partitions are determined by just two sets each one with two red balls and one blue ball, as the third set will be determined by the other balls. Moreover: we can differentiate these two sets depending on the blue ball that contain, thus we have partitions determined by these two sets

$$
\{r_j,r_k,b_1\}\text{ and }\{r_l,r_i,b_2\}
$$

Thus the number of these sets are determined by pairs of distinct sets $(\{j,k\},\{l,i\})$ such that $j,k,l$ and $i$ are distinct elements of $I:=\{1,\ldots,7\}$. This is equivalent to, first, choose all distinct subsets of two elements of $I$, and after with the remaining elements choose over all distinct subsets of two elements.

This amounts to $\binom{7}{2}\cdot \binom{5}{2}=7\cdot 6\cdot 5=210$.